# Magento:: Multiple countries and multi languages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We started one big brand website in Magento they are targeting different giographic locations. So we need to implement multiple countries and multiple languages. For instance selected country is Canada then we may have three languages English,French,Spanish.

Please advise me how to set up this in magento. I heard lot more about the multiple websites, but I am searching for good practices.

Please refer the below pic 
[image]

Comment: Did you created countries as website or countries as stores ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have countries as websites and languages as store views for those websites.
In your case: Canada is the website with 3 Store Views: Canada English, Canada French and Canada Spanish. You can see some of the settings [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/multi-store_set_up/how_to_automatically_redirect_to_a_store_view_based_on_the_browser_language)
This will give you a control for products, categories and other entities from Magento on country level (website), but will make your site slower for example indexing is at website level and now it will take the amount of time it normally takes multiplied by the number of websites.

Comment: Thanks for nice explaianation. Is countries as website or countries as stores , which is better ?